# Search to Compare and generate a new table result

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, pattern-matching, splunk

In need of finding a way to search to compare and generate a communication-relation table which apparently seem to involve some complex logic.

I have a table with two columns where one lists the servers and the other shows the list of different servers that it communicates with (how it communicates is out of the scope of requirement).

Need to search for different servers that apparently communicate with one another in one or the other way. The sample image added here will explain the source and expected result tables.

[image]

Please let me know if and/or how this could be achieved in SQL Server or Splunk.

Comment: Are you able to modify the table and how the data is inserted? This would be much simpler if the data values were stored in columns in a 1:N relationship, rather than comma separated values.

Comment: The source table and the desired output are incredibly challenging here because both of them violate 1NF by storing multiple data points in a single tuple. But your output doesn't make much sense either. Why are some in Group1 and others in Group2? What defines a group? And how do you sort those groups? First you need to normalize this structure. Then I am guessing you need a recursive cte.

Comment: Looking at this closer you are really facing a struggle here. You have circular references. Meaning that for S1 you state it communicates with S2. But then in S2 it states it communicates with S1. A recursive cte here is going to crash because it is circular.

Comment: @Shreesha . . . Fix your data model!  You should not be storing lists as strings.  I would be surprised if anyone would help to solve this problem, using the data  model you have defined.

Comment: @Jacob H I am able to modify the table but that is not suggested. This table I have given here is just a small representation of the actual table which holds such similar entries in many thousands rows. So hence I am in need of finding a way to do it by using this just as a source table and create intermediate table as required.

Comment: @Sean Lange Why,what & how among your questions are not in scope here but let me tell you that - this is about different servers and which all other servers they're communicating to in an environment. All servers communicating to one another are chosen and identified as Group1 and same goes with next set of servers which would be called Group2 and so on. G1 servers will have no communication with any G2 servers. This is for performing certain actions on each server group post grouping. We're getting source info from a discovery tool. Groups are sorted based on GroupName as they'll be unique.

Comment: Not sure how trying to get clarification of the results is out of scope. You need to use recursion for the results. Since everything I have asked you consider out of scope there is nothing I can do to help. I hope you find a solution.